# Security measures for AJAX-PHP scripts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

For a link like this
     DELETE

i am using this ajax call

```js
$(function() {
$(".delete_msgs").click(function() {
var msgid = $(this).attr("id");
var dataString4 = 'msgid=' + msgid;
$('a#'+msgid).html('<img src="img/loader.gif" class="loading" />'); 
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "del_msg.php",
 data: dataString4,
 cache: false,
 success: function(data){
    if (data == 0) {
 //alert('Sent!');
 } else {
    $('a#'+msgid).html(data);
 $('.viewmessage'+msgid).hide();
 }
 }  

});
return false;
});
});
```

The del_msg.php file contains that code:

```
if(isset($_POST)) {
$msgid = $_POST['msgid']; 
$delmsg = mysql_query("DELETE FROM messages
WHERE id = $msgid") or die(mysql_error());
echo 'Message sent!';
} else {
echo 0;
}
```

My big question is, how can i protect my send throught AJAX function? Anyone can change the id of the #a element and, consequently, can delete any row from my database.
Is there a more secure way to call php with ajax, or at least, to hide my important variables sent via ajax?

Comment: Not only can anyone delete any row ( good spot on your part) but anyone can cause your entire database to be deleted! Your query is open to exploitation by SQL injection. You should use PDO bound queries to mitigate this.

Comment: Just use prepared statements. Or if you _really_ need to, you can validate the parameter.

Comment: As for protecting against the deletion of a row by anyone who shouldn't be able to, you will have to introduce some way to authenticate users, to provide the ability to determine who is authorised and who isn't.

Comment: And preferably you should use a "DELETE" instead of a "POST", but using links is scary since if someone uses some sort of page preloader extension, they can wipe your whole db.